Robotic Manipulator Path Planning on Torus Topology
I'm working on path planning for the robotic manipulator. As I understand from the literature, the system's c-space is represented by an n-dimensional torus. I used most RRT from OMPL library by installing it with Moveit2.
Does the library support a torus space planning?
